# ListView with Windows 7 column header style

Tags: c#, .net, listview, uxtheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetUIHWND and DirectUIHWND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd)

I've seen that Windows 7 introduced a new listview style which even differs from the Windows Vista one. Columns have a fade-to-white and animate while reordering them.
In Windows Vista the columns only had a glossy white-gray gradient and didn't animate while reordering.

In C#, I know it is possible to retrieve the Vista-like style by using SetTheme from uxtheme.dll, but I didn't find a code snippet to get the Windows 7 style.

How to retrieve the Windows 7-only ListView style?