# Add drop shadow to ListView (Icon mode)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

If you look at the thumbnail images in Windows Explorer you'll notice that they have a drop shadow, is this effect associated with the ListView control or does Windows Explorer does some extra coding to accomplish this effect?

---

**Edit:**

So it turned out that Windows uses another control. So my question now is how can I add a drop shadow to the "normal" ListView.

Comment: Explorer doesn't use the system list view control

Comment: Does it use a control that we don't have access to?

Comment: Yes indeed it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd

Comment: That's compilcated... You could well enough end up making a semi-transparent bitmap and blurring it just to make a shadow...

Comment: @Mints97 How is it complicated, I mean what should I learn in order to be able to do it. I have an idea, which is to draw the drop shadow on the image itself, I have tried this and it worked great, however there is a problem: When I select the ListView item then the drop shadow is also shown selected! So is there a way to only let a part of the ListView item to be shown selected (the part which does not have the drop shadow)?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and there aren't any drop shadows for the thumbnail images. Could you add a screenshot to your question to describe the effect you are after?

Answer (score 1):

For a standard list view, you may want to use a technique called custom draw (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569(v=vs.85).aspx).

Basically, you ask your list view not to draw its items, but instead send you some window messages for you to draw them yourself. This is a very flexible but also troublesome technique, because you need to handle many things (like whether an item is selected/disabled, font, color etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The drop shadow you see in Windows Explorer is not publicly available for you to use. So you will have to custom-draw the items (NM_CUSTOMDRAW) by yourself.

Not sure if such effect is available in GDI/GDI+, but Direct2D does have one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/drop-shadow