# How to replicate Windows Explorer column filtering on ListView control header

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I'm trying to implement column filtering on a `ListView` control (Windows Forms/c#/win32 via pinvoke), the same way that Windows Explorer does. For those that haven't used it before it looks like this:

[image]

When you hover over the column header a drop down arrow appears, clicking the drop down displays a context menu with various filtering options. Once you have selected an option the arrow image changes to a tick mark image that is always visible, like this:
[image]

I've got the drop down arrow to display by sending a HDM_SETITEM message to the ListView with the `HDF_SPLITBUTTON` format flag specified. I can also display the filtering menu.

The problem I have is that I can't figure how to display the "tick" image. Well other than resorting to using owner drawing, which really seems like an overkill. I've gone through the API documentation for ListView and Header controls and there doesn't seem to be any windows message you can send to change the image.

To work around it I tried using a header image to indicate that filtering is active, but according to the HDITEM documentation you can't use `HDF_IMAGE` or `HDF_BITMAP` at the same time as `HDF_SORTUP` or `HDF_SORTDOWN`. So then I created new images to indicate both sorting and filtering state, but now all my `ListView` items are indented by the size of the column header image (seems to be a known issue with the c# `ListView` control).

I did find something that looked promising: `BCM_SETSPLITINFO` lets you set the glyph of a split button. However I have a ListView Header, not a Split Button, unless the Header has child windows that are Split Buttons...

So does any one have any ideas how to replicate that "tick" mark without implementing a full owner drawn solution?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: It looks like a ListView, [but it is not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd).

Comment: Ah! That would explain it, I haven't heard of DirectUIHWND before. No wonder I've had such a hard time with the Win32 ListView control.  I actually did try Spy++, but I only got as far as figuring out that the header is a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

If you need real good thing, you will resort to owner draw eventually. I don't think header-control gives any message/notification/notify-reflect for this thing.

For now, you can just *fool* the user by having tick mark symbol on the very left of column name. If no tick, display set of blank spaces on left. You cannot put such symbol on right, as user may resize the column, and tick mark wont be on the very right.

Depending on selected font, set of spaces you put instead of tick symbol may more or less.

Comment: I'm currently using the "put an image to the left of the column name" trick, that was the best work around I could come up with. Unfortunately the .Net control doesn't handle that so well, so I've resorted to manually setting the header image list using HDM_SETIMAGELIST. That mostly worked, but now when I clear the image (LVM_SETCOLUMN with iImage = I_IMAGENONE) the header isn't realigning the text i.e. the image is gone, but the space that was allocated for it is still there.

Comment: In order to suppress this space, you have to reset `HDF_IMAGE` in `item.fmt` (located in `HDITEM` structure).