# Is there a way for c# to dock onscreen keyboard of windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, on-screen-keyboard

You can open the Windows 10 on-screen keyboard from C# code using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Is there a way in C# to dock this keyboard to the bottom of the screen when opened?
I need to create the same effect that 'dock' button does on the onscreen keyboard itself.

Comment: You can try this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project

Comment: Pleas see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/. may be help you.

Comment: There are two on-screen-keyboards in Windows 8+, osk.exe is the old one from Windows 2000/XP.

Comment: Win10 uses a very different way to display the OSK, so olden hacks are not going to work anymore.  It is not much of a practical problem, the user simply clicks "Mv Dn" once and that's it, it remembers where it was displayed last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

osk.exe supports a undocumented command line parameter `/dockbottom`. However, running `osk.exe /dockbottom` just places the keyboard at the bottom of your screen, it is not exactly the same as docking. I don't know how far back this parameter works but I confirmed it works in Windows 8 and 10.

I don't think there is a way to actually dock ([app bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/application-desktop-toolbars) docking) programmatically. Faking a click on the UI button might work but you would have to use UI Automation because it is not a real button, the whole window is a [DirectUIHWND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd) window.

As a hack you can set a REG_DWORD called `Dock` to `1` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Osk` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATConfig\osk` (this is a volatile key so you must open it as such) while osk.exe is not running. When you start it again it will read the dock setting and start docked.

Note: This docking mode is not available if the screen resolution is set too low.

Windows 8 and later also have a different on-screen-keyboard called the touch keyboard. You can control this keyboard with [`IFrameworkInputPane`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150608-00/?p=45431/).

Comment: The registry workaround seems to work, but the problem is that when the user clicks the (highlighted) dock button, it also changes the registry value, so next time, it would start undocked again. Any trick apart from modifying the registry value each time I need to show the on screen keyboard? Because for that the app would have to run elevated right?

Comment: @aros you don't have to be elevated to write to HKCU.

Comment: Oh really? Interesting. Will try that then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Quite late, but yes, I can confirm that I was able to write to HKCU with no elevation.